# App Engine no output in browser

Tags: php, google-app-engine, dev-appserver, roots-sage

Running app engine local server with a Wordpress for App Engine build and using a Sage theme.

Installed all dependencies and gulp build task seems to run ok.

Then run dev_appserver.py and check browser (Chrome) at localhost:8080. Browser shows blank screen.

I inspect the blank page and it shows there is no html.

Not sure what to check next, or what may be the cause?

**(Edit) App Engine dev console log**

This is what happens when I run dev_appserver.py and hit refresh in browser a couple of times:

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK! Run "gcloud -h" to get the list of available commands.
---

C:\dev>cd projects/romac-website

C:\dev\projects\romac-website>dev_appserver.py .
INFO     2017-11-14 12:41:43,490 devappserver2.py:105] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-11-14 12:41:45,032 api_server.py:300] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55664
INFO     2017-11-14 12:41:45,200 dispatcher.py:251] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-11-14 12:41:45,200 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2017-11-14 12:41:56,894 module.py:821] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 301 -
INFO     2017-11-14 12:41:56,908 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2017-11-14 12:45:15,813 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2017-11-14 12:45:15,933 module.py:821] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 32038
INFO     2017-11-14 12:45:23,256 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2017-11-14 12:45:23,269 module.py:821] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 32038
INFO     2017-11-14 12:46:05,604 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2017-11-14 12:46:05,617 module.py:821] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 32038
```

**In-Browesr view**

Here is what I see in browser (nothing):

[image]

And then go to inspect the page, no html etc:

[image]

Comment: Actually there is some (empty) html, it looks like your app is not building the response as you're expecting it to. You need to debug it.

Comment: Yes I think your right, how do I debug it in development environment?

Comment: Depends on your programming language, IDE - if it has a debugger, etc. I prefer code inspection plus adding `logging.error()` calls in the code which are immediately visible in the devserver logs, it's usually fastest.

Comment: OK Im just using notepad++ rather than an IDE. Where would I add this logging.error() call? top of the index.php fie? or somewhere else?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not a php user, I mistakenly thought you're using python ...

Comment: Thats ok Dan, this project is Wordpress so need to use PHP ... Is the concept still the same though? to add a line of code to the project so that App Engine dev server writes out a log of some kind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158917/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-timothyaura).